# When closing session in my app and return to login my DisplayAlert's are shown several times

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, authentication, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app with xamarin.forms in which I have a login, I use the MessagingCenter to send certain messages from my viewmodels to my pages, such as a message that tells my page that it should trigger a DisplayAlert when the user enters incorrectly Your login features in the LoginPage.
The probelama I have is that if I log in to my app, I go back to the LoginPage and enter wrong data my DisplayAlert is displayed twice or the number of times I have closed session + 1, I think the problem may be due to two instances remaining or more, different from my LoginPage existing in memory and when sending messages through MessagingCenter all these pages are receiving them and executing actions based on them.

Note: When checking credentials change MainPage so that it is now a master detail page.

Note 2: I realized that after closing session if I change the app or put it in the background and return to it, the DisplayAlerts are no longer displayed multiple times.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Try to `Unsubscribe`  the notification before you `subscribe` everytime. For example, `MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<LogonViewModel>(this, "ErrorCredentials");` and then  `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LogonViewModel>(this, "ErrorCredentials", async (sender) =>
        {}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must be subscribing a second time to the message when your LoginPage is displayed.
This means the LoginPage will receive the message twice, and therefore display the popup twice.
Try to unsubscribe when moving off the LoginPage.

Comment: I just made tests with break points and that's exactly what happens, when I arrive for the second time to my LoginPage, I subscribe twice to the message. The problem is that since the page I need to see when I log in is a master detail page, I am MainPage = MasterDetalPage (), this is displayed correctly, but as a result I do not do a PushAsync from my LoginPage to my MasterDetailPage, OnDisAppearing is never fired.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: It is difficult to offer any advice without any source code

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert ();

Instead of using MessaginCenter

Extracted from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755941/button-back-to-my-app-in-the-background-and-when-you-resume-it-starts-again?noredirect=1#comment94401873_53755941)